# Alloy - Check predicate is correct?

Tags: predicate, alloy, predicates

I'm currently playing around with predicates in Alloy. I know that I can use `assert` and `check` statements to confirm that my model is working as it should. However, is there any way to check that a predicate I have created has done what I expect? Or do I just have to show the instances and search through them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just say what you "expect", and set it up as an assertion. Unfortunately, Alloy does not currently have a mind-reading command :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, makes sense now!